# Install ROS Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having difficulty following the wiki

http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update-2  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update-2  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  InRelease
Ign:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  InRelease
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local  InRelease
Ign:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local  InRelease
Get:4 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local-cublas-performance-update-1  InRelease
Ign:4 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local-cublas-performance-update-1  InRelease
Get:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local  InRelease
Ign:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local  InRelease
Get:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update-2  Release [574 B]
Get:7 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release [574 B]
Get:8 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local  Release [574 B]
Get:9 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local-cublas-performance-update-1  Release [574 B]
Get:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update-2  Release [574 B]
Get:10 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local  Release [574 B]
Get:7 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release [574 B]
Get:8 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local  Release [574 B]
Get:9 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local-cublas-performance-update-1  Release [574 B]
Get:10 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-1-local  Release [574 B]   
Ign:12 http://packages.linuxmint.com sylvia InRelease                                
Hit:13 http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease                      
Hit:14 http://packages.linuxmint.com sylvia Release                                  
Ign:15 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                        
Ign:17 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia InRelease                           
Ign:18 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia Release                             
Hit:20 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                          
Ign:21 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main amd64 Packages                 
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease      
Hit:23 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                          
Hit:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                             
Hit:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                   
Ign:26 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main i386 Packages                  
Ign:28 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main all Packages                   
Ign:29 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en_US              
Hit:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                     
Ign:31 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en   
Ign:21 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main amd64 Packages                 
Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease             
Hit:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease        
Ign:26 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main i386 Packages       
Ign:28 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en
Ign:21 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en
Ign:21 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en
Ign:21 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en
Err:21 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Ign:26 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/sylvia/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It is ignoring my changes to the repository.

I was not able to accomplish the first step: "Configure your Ubuntu repositories". Linux Mint is essentially Ubuntu but the interface is different. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291698/install-ros-linux-mint-18.3-sylvia/) by [gm9089zo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35307/gm9089zo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> It is ignoring my changes to the repository.

Which makes sense, as `sylvia` is not an Ubuntu release code name, and the ROS buildfarm does not build packages for it (or at least: it doesn't store any *release file* for it).

> ```
> Err:21 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main amd64 Packages
> ```

```
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Ign:26 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sylvia Release' does not have a Release file.
```

This error also tells you that.

> Linux Mint is essentially Ubuntu but the interface is different. Does anyone know how to do that?

Provided `sylvia` is compatible with one of Ubuntu's distributions (I haven't checked), you can try to see whether setting `ROS_OS_OVERRIDE` ([docs](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE)) to a suitable value works. Be sure to also update your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` to use the same value(s).

Finally: how to install ROS Ubuntu packages on Ubuntu derivatives has been asked a few times before. A search (with Google: `site:answers.ros.org <your search terms>`) should lead you to some usable information.

---

Edit: looks like `sylvia` is essentially Ubuntu Xenial. A value for `ROS_OS_OVERRIDE` could be: `ubuntu:16.04`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gm9089zo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35307/gm9089zo/) on 2018-05-20**:
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, this post talks about the same problem:

https://answers.ros.org/question/245325/troubles-installing-ros-kinetic-on-linux-mint-sarah-18/

There problems is, when you add the Ros repository, you need to change the name of the release to Ubuntu's release name, in this case Xenial. So, instead of use

> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

You should change for

> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

Because, otherwise, the repository uses the Mint distribution name, and there isn't.

---

Originally posted by [Pedro Alcantara](https://answers.ros.org/users/25284/pedro-alcantara/) with karma: 56 on 2018-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gm9089zo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35307/gm9089zo/) on 2018-05-20**:
Yes, this is also correct. Thank you. I should've been able to crack it myself. :-)

**Comment by [Diogo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/40037/diogo42/) on 2019-09-14**:
Thank`s this works for me